# What is an effective way to learn vimscript?

Tags: vimscript

Let's say I've been working with vim for some time; I've dabbled with my `~/.vimrc` and copied-and-pasted some snippets in I find on the way, with minimal changes.

I'm beginning to get a hazy understanding of this weird language called vimscript. What is an effective way for me to develop a greater understanding of it?

Comment: IMHO this question is off-topic because it is too broad, in addition, it's basically asking for "what's the best VimScript tutorial" (even though it isn't phrased like that). I don't think we want to have questions asking for off-site resources...

Comment: @Carpetsmoker I do not agree! We can have questions listing other online resources on the topic. Since SE is community-driven, if a resource gets out-dated, disappears, changes link etc., there is always someone to correct it. However, I think I agree that it's better to keep such question for later, because _they are very tricky_.

Comment: Treatment of this genre of questions [is being discussed on Meta](http://meta.vi.stackexchange.com/q/38/24).

Comment: Write a plugin.

Comment: @Rich I have :)

Comment: @AndrewFerrier In that case I think you might be underselling yourself by describing your understanding as "hazy" :). Other things that have helped me: 1. Learn Vimscript the Hard Way (tick!) and 2. Answering questions on this site (with all the poring through the `:help` that that entails).

Answer (score 4):

I have found [Learn Vimscript the Hard Way](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/) to be invaluable in improving my understanding of vimscript. It covers both the theory (as a programming language) as well as improving my understanding of vim as an editor. Recommended.